# href target rel change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("a[href$='youtube']").attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto');
```

I'm attempting to target any links on a page with youtube in the `href`. I want to add a `rel="prettyPhoto"` to them so they open in the lightbox window. Any suggestions why the above code doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: first thing I'd suggest is to confirm that the selector works (i.e. `alert($("a[href$='youtube']").length)`) as there could be two potential issues here.

Comment: the selector doesn't seem to be working. any suggestions why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN9MmXAuWPg?ajax=true" class="read-more" </a>      I'm attempting to add this to a wordpress setup dynamically. The link exists in a gallery for example. . .

Comment: That is invalid HTML.  This could be why you can't get this to work.

Comment: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN9MmXAuWPg?ajax=true" class="read-more"</a>     That's the correct example href. My apologies for the mistake before (was removing the excess CSS so as to not confuse)  --- EDIT: weird, the semicolon appears on StackOverflow for some reason. let's try this...

Comment: $("a[href*='youtube']") as mentioned in one of the answers should return any link that contains youtube like the one you have provided here.

Comment: Both of the example anchors you have posted are invalid HTML...

Comment: It's just stack overflow changing them when I post it. Having trouble getting code to work on SO. The links should be valid.

Comment: of course they are invalid but I should that is not the mistake and it is just a bad copy and paste...correct?

Comment: @Bernard, please mark html sections as code by putting the \` symbol on either side of the code.

Comment: Correct. As mentioned, StackOverflow is adding excess characters for some odd reason after my url. The link in my document is valid I can assure you.

Comment: @Bernard, you can also create a reproduction of what you are dealing with on jsFiddle.net and then post the link here.

Comment: If you change the selector and alerting the length returns more than 0 then that should be good. If it is still not working maybe you could provide some code you're using to make use of the rel value?

Comment: `<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN9MmXAuWPg?ajax=true" class="read-more"</a>`

Comment: It's still invalid!!!! :)  Try updating your question with the code rather than adding the code as a comment.  This will allow us to see exactly what you pasted in...

Comment: Surely you can't tell me the above code is invalid. I'm going ballistic! The code is actually being generated via a wordpress plugin. I'm just trying to add prettyPhoto to the output of the WP plugin. Hence why it's a bit difficult to show you the code. Let me see what I can muster up. Thank you for the help thus far!

Comment: @Bernard now I am concerned lol...are you sure you have a well formed href? If you do, then you should definately be getting a number higher than 0 by alerting the `$("a[href*='youtube']").length` as indicated in @Abe's answer.

Comment: Definitely post your next code sample into your question and not a comment.  A valid anchor would look like this: `<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN9MmXAuWPg?ajax=true" class="read-more">Link text</a>`

Comment: @Bernard best thing to do is to view the page source find the href and copy that...if that results in what you have pasted here that is not well formed as it is missing the closing carrot > on the opening <A> tag and does not have anything to click.

Comment: `<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN9MmXAuWPg?ajax=true" class="read-more" style="display: block; height: 380px; width: 980px; background-color: transparent; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 3; cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;</a>`

Comment: and then in my header php file:
`<script type="text/javascript">
alert("test");
alert($("a[href*='youtube']").length);
</script>`   however, when opening the page I'm only seeing an alert of 'test'

Comment: Do you see any errors reported by your browser? What happens if you try `alert($)` instead of the second alert you currently have there?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
jQuery("a[href*='youtube']").attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto');
alert(jQuery("a[href*='youtube']").length);
});
</script>`    Corrected the issue of it not seeing the youtube link. Now it's just a matter of actually adding that rel. Not sure why it can't seem to add it. . .

Comment: Here is the short hand version on executing some code after the DOM has loaded `jQuery(document).ready(function() {//do stuff when DOM has loaded});`. If you have a public facing URL I could take a look.

Comment: Sorry it's not public. And having it load after the DOM is loaded will cause my check for youtube links = 0.

Comment: @Bernard how do you know that it is not being added? Are you able to use Firebug or the IE developer toolbar to test this after your call to `jQuery("a[href*='youtube']").attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto');` is made? From the Firebug console you could run `jQuery("a[href*='youtube']:first").attr('rel')` to see if rel is being set or even call that in an alert right after the call that sets the rel on those hrefs. Unfortunately, I've got to run But my best advice is to break the problem by moving through it step by step. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a[href*='youtube']").attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto');
```

The `*` is the [Attribute Contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUVRf/1/

**UPDATE:**

In your comments you posted `<a href="youtube.com/watch?v=NN9MmXAuWPg?ajax=true"; class="read-more" </a>` as an example href.  This is invalid HTML and would explain why the code is not working.

Comment: Tried it but it's not working. Added an alert after and it won't get to it.

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error is?  Try putting an alert before that line and see if it gets to that.  What error is it throwing?  You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUVRf/1/

Answer (score 2):

$= is ends with, do your hrefs end with youtube, perhaps you want $("a[href*='youtube']")

Comment: I changed that but it's still not working. I put in an alert right after and it still isn't getting to the alert.

Comment: It works for me, I just tested it and that code adds a rel="prettyPhoto" to any link on a page containing youtube, do you have jquery referenced correctly? do you use anything like firebug to debug javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `prettyPhoto` is actively listening for your `rel` change.  You would need to either change this rel before HTML is sent to user (server side), OR after the rel change, re-initialize the prettyPhoto lightbox functionality so it attaches to your proper `rel` tags